# Setting up Tomcat in nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, tomcat, proxy, tomcat7

I'm setting up my web server and I need to run tomcat on `http://ip/tomcat/` instead of `http://ip:8080/`. How I can do this on nginx?
I've tried to find an answer in the internet, but all of them is useless for me.

My nginx configuration:

```
upstream tomcat {
    server ip:8080;
}

server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location /tomcat/ {
                proxy_pass http://tomcat;
        }

}
```

Server answer:
[server answer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZR65.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use /tomcat/ location with using below tag.

```
location /tomcat/ {
                proxy_pass http://tomcat/;
        }
```

When you are going  to access manager page it opens http://IP/manager instead of http://IP/tomcat/manager cause /manager/html is harded in tomcat webapps/ROOT/index.jsp

```
<div class="button">
                        <a class="container shadow" href="/manager/html"><span>Manager App</span></a>
                    </div>
```

If you want to access manager through tomcat location then change below code in tomcat ROOT/index.jsp

```
<div class="button">
                        <a class="container shadow" href="/tomcat/manager/html"><span>Manager App</span></a>
                    </div>
```

Restart tomcat and test.

Answer (score 0):

Use below reverse proxy and test.

```
location /tomcat/ {
                proxy_pass http://tomcat/;
        }
```

Note: In IP address you need to use tomcat IP.

Comment: It works, but there are a new problem. Tomcat working on `http://IP/tomcat`, but when I going to manager it opens `http://IP/manager` instead of `http://IP/tomcat/manager`.

Comment: Use below location tag and test. 

`location / {
                proxy_pass http://IP:8080/;
        }`

Access application using `http://IP/` and `http://IP/manager`

Comment: Yeah, it works, but I need that tomcat will be on `http://IP/tomcat`

Comment: Maybe I can to start up tomcat on `http://IP:80/tomcat` instead of `http://IP:8080/`?